# How to get value from Drool file in Java

Tags: java, drools

Using the insert method, I am able to pass the value from Java to Drool file,  but after the operation I want the return value from the Drool file.

Comment: You have to write the Java program and the rules in such a way that you get the values you want into objects you can access from Java. This, admittedly, is a very general answer, but so is your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return anything from a drool file . It works by reference . 
Below 3 activities happen from your java class :

- Insert the Fact Data in KieSession
- Fire the rule using the fact data
- Use the fact data after the rule gets fired

  ```
  class TdpFactData{
     private int age ....
             getter , setters ....
      }
        ----------------------------------------
   TdpFactData factData=new TdpFactData();

   kieSession.insert(factData); Fact data is inserted in kiesession for the drool to use 

   kieSession.fireAllRules(); // Here the drool file executes 

   // Fact data got changed based on the rules 
   //Utilize the fact data again in java code .
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetObjectsCommand object to get values from drool session. To do this, first create a session object from kiecontainer.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = ks.getKieClassPathContainer() ;
    String session = "session" //session name from kmodeule.xml
    StatelessKieSession session = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession(sessionName);
    List<Command<?>> cmds = new ArrayList<Command<?>>();
        KieCommands commands = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();
        cmds.add(commands.newInsert("hi)); //insert all POJO here.
        
        GetObjectsCommand getObjectsCommand = new GetObjectsCommand();
        getObjectsCommand.setOutIdentifier("objects");

        
        cmds.add(commands.newFireAllRules());
        cmds.add(getObjectsCommand);

        BatchExecutionCommand myCommands = CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds);
        ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = session.executeCommandsWithResults( myCommands);
                
        List responseList = (List) response.getResult().getValue("objects");
    //the response list will contain the objects present plus inserted via drool engine.
```